# Include "order" in Regex but exclude "in order" in Regex using python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, regex-negation

I am using regex in python to find phrases containing keywords related to supply issues. The keywords I am targeting are: `suppl(y|ies)|order|parcel|deliver|product`

here **order** refers to an order made online for some product but I am getting a lot of phrases containing the phrase **in order** e.g.,

```
so, in order to minimize the chances of the signal getting blocked
```

How do I change my regex such that this issue is resolved.

I have tried to use `[^] negation` but it only works on characters and not full words.

I have also used negative lookahead `(?:(?!in order).)*` but I could not find boolean AND operator like the boolean OR operator `|`

Comment: Use `r'suppl(y|ies)|(?<!\bin )order|parcel|deliver|product'`

Comment: thanks, works like a charm